# How to access specific index in array and change its background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pagination

Im making a pagination in react my problem is that when the page loads it should set color to 1st element in array indicating page 1 and also if i click the 1st or last button is should highlight the 1st or last page.Css focus works only if i click the page number.

```
<button>First Item</button>
<div>{pages number}</div> // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
<button>Last Item</button>

.btnpage{
background-color:green;
}

.btnpage:focus {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should edit your post's content to have [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since the current content is incomplete and doesn't show where it went wrong.